# How to pass soap as a string to php soapclient

Tags: php, soap

I have following soap string.

```
$str = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
$str .= '<soapenv:Header/>';
$str .= '<soapenv:Body>';
$str .= '<Username>uname1</Username>';
$str .= '<Password>upassword1</Password>';
$str .= '<RequestType>GetDiamonds</RequestType>';
$str .= '<ClientId>51</ClientId>';
$str .= '<MySoapReq>';
$str .= '<Params>';
$str .= '<Diamond_ID>%18112%</Diamond_ID>';
$str .= '<Diamond_ID>%1625%</Diamond_ID>';
$str .= '<Diamond_ID>%18625%</Diamond_ID>';
$str .= '</Params>';
$str .= '</MySoapReq>';
$str .= '</soapenv:Body>';
$str .= '</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

I am trying to call it in following way but not getting how I will pass above string to soap request.

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => 'http://localhost:8080/testsoap',
                                     'uri'=>'http://localhost:8080/testsoap'
                                     ));
```

I have also tried giving username and password here but it did not work then I tried following.

```
$return = $client->__soapCall("GetDiamonds",
   array(new SoapParam($str))
);
```

Any suggestions how I can pass above string in soap request and get response? Am I doing in a right way or there should be other method for this?

Answer (score 0):

The best and fast way to pass the parameters to the Soap Web Service is to use a WSDL to php generator as you won't wonder how to construct the request.

Try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project and you'll see it's easy to construct the request (without making any error unless you're doing it purposely ;)). In addition, the received response is easily handled. Each part is an object.